# Adding values between range of values in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a SSRS report and I am having a one dimension table and it contain one field "No_Of_Stories" and one fact table with column "Total_TIV" . I want an output in the following format.

```
Range  | TIV  
1      | 1000  
2 to 3 | 20000  
4 to 7 | 30000
```

Is there any method to solve this using SQL query itself or is there any expression in SSRS to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN No_Of_Stories = 1 THEN '1'
    WHEN No_Of_Stories >= 2 AND No_Of_Stories < 4 THEN '2 to 3'
    WHEN No_Of_Stories >= 4 AND No_Of_Stories < 8 THEN '4 to 7'
    -- Add any other ranges here
    ELSE 'More than 7' -- or whatever the maximum range is
  END As Range,
  SUM(TIV) AS Total_TIV
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN No_Of_Stories = 1 THEN '1'
    WHEN No_Of_Stories >= 2 AND No_Of_Stories < 4 THEN '2 to 3'
    WHEN No_Of_Stories >= 4 AND No_Of_Stories < 8 THEN '4 to 7'
    -- Add any other ranges here
    ELSE 'More than 7' -- or whatever the maximum range is
  END
ORDER BY Max(No_Of_Stories)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, i got one more question ! .. what if i want one more column like "Difference" where its value came from following equation Difference = (Total TIV of All the rows-Total TIV of individual rows)

Comment: If this solves your problem, please tick it as the accepted answer so other people searching for this know the solution works (upvotes are also appreciated :) ). For the other issue, you should make this a separate question so it can be addressed there - questions on StackOverflow should be about one issue, they are not a conversation like traditional forums. I can quickly answer that once it is in its own question.